# i want a C++ priority-queue implement, and when the element is popped, the corresponding queue space is released？

Tags: c++, priority-queue

Which C++ third-party library implements the queue, and when the element is popped, the corresponding queue space is released？

c++ stl library support queue.but when i pop() some elements,queue use memory does not be samll.So i want to find a third-party library which can solve this problem.

Comment: It's not quite clear from your question what you need. Do you want a queue that releases unused memory as soon as you call ```queue.pop()```?

Comment: yes,i want a queue,if i queue.pop(),the memory queue used will be less immediately

Comment: why is `std::queue` not ok? `std::queue::pop` does remove the element from the queue, and deleting the element is part of that

Comment: memory as tracked by the implementation, or memory as tracked by the operating system? You might need to switch implementation if you want the latter.

Comment: It's quite common for Operating Systems to manage memory at page-level granularity. Even if you pop some elements, your memory use (in the eyes of the OS) may be the same. Since this is OS behavior, all libraries will have the same effect.

Comment: For me this sound s like [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). Please describe your actual problem then we can provide better solution and explain why your approach with alternative queue is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The C++ standard library has a class that suits your needs: It's `std::list`. Just use its `push_front` and `pop_back` member functions. The memory of any element you pop will immediately be freed.

Note that this is only worth the trouble if your elements are large. Otherwise, the allocation overhead of the linked list nodes will outweigh the advantage of freeing nodes immediately.

Also keep in mind that your `malloc` implementation won't give the memory back to the operating system immediately. (Or at all, really. Looking at you, glibc.) So you may not see the program's memory usage decrease immediately, anyway. However, your program can immediately re-use the memory of any freed nodes.

Comment: but list can not sort the element。i need a priority_queue.Pop the largest or smallest element by a certain size rule

Comment: You didn't say that in your question. In that case, you'll most likely have to create your own max-heap data structure using a tree instead of a flat array of elements. However, unless you're really struggling to free up a few kilobytes of data, this isn't worth it. If you're talking about freeing up megabytes of memory, you most likely have a memory leak and not an inefficient queue.